# How to fix my QClipboard object's behavior?

Tags: qt, qclipboard

I'm working with `QClipboard` object under Windows 10.
Just trying to see what's inside the clipboard when I press `Ctrl-C` on some sample text.
As you can see the results are very inconsistent and I cannot grasp why exactly.

**Code:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(QApplication::clipboard(), SIGNAL(dataChanged()), this, SLOT(showClipboard()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::showClipboard()
{
    qDebug() << "Clipboard is empty:" << QApplication::clipboard()->text().isEmpty()
             << ":" << QApplication::clipboard()->text();
}
```

**Sample output:**

```
Clipboard is empty: false : ""
Clipboard is empty: true : ""
Clipboard is empty: false : "sample text"
Clipboard is empty: false : "sample text"
Clipboard is empty: true : ""
Clipboard is empty: false : ""
Clipboard is empty: false : ""
Clipboard is empty: false : ""
Clipboard is empty: false : "sample text"
Clipboard is empty: true : ""
Clipboard is empty: false : "sample text"
Clipboard is empty: true : ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that introduction of a pause before calling `QApplication::clipboard()->text()` fixes this issue.
`QTimer` or plain `Sleep()`/`nanoSleep()` (Windows/Linux) can be used to achieve the effect.

**QTimer Example:**

```
connect(QApplication::clipboard(), SIGNAL(dataChanged()), this, SLOT(showClipboard()));

void MainWindow::showClipboard()
{
    QTimer::singleShot(50, this, qDebug() << QApplication::clipboard()->text());
}
```

**Windows `Sleep()` Example:**

```
connect(QApplication::clipboard(), SIGNAL(dataChanged()), this, SLOT(showClipboard()));

void MainWindow::showClipboard()
{
    Sleep(50);
    qDebug() << QApplication::clipboard()->text();
}
```

Comment: Do not use Sleep (maybe nanoSleep) in a GUI since if the time is greater than 30 ms it will block the GUI avoiding other internal tasks to be executed

Comment: It will block the GUI indeed, thank you for pointing that out.
People will have to figure out how they will manage that (e. g. create a separate thread), I just wanted to get the info about the fix out here, because I found none.

Comment: You have not understood me, the correct solution in the world of Qt is to use a QTimer. the threads would bring other problems as you can not directly access the GUI from another thread. In conclusion the best solution is the QTimer since it is simple and does not generate other problems